# Using numpy's function loadtxt() to read a two column file then using polyfit() to return an array

Tags: python

afile is a given file, and z the degree of the polynomial. Been breaking my head over this for a while, frustrating how I'm basically given zero instructions on how to proceed.

This is what I thought it should be like:

```
import numpy as np
def newfile(afile,z):
    x,y = np.loadtxt(afile)
    d= np.polyfit(x,y,z)
    return d
```

I have attempted to do it as

```
data = np.loadtxt(afile)
x = data[0:]
```

by printing "data" I'm given this format:

```
[[   2.      888.8425]
 [   6.      888.975 ]
 [  14.      888.1026]
 [  17.      888.2071]
 [  23.      886.0479]
 [  26.      883.3316]
 [  48.      877.04  ]
 [ 99.       854.3665]]
```

By printing "x" in this case just gives me the whole list (I'm thinking the issue lies in the lack of comma). In this case I'd want x to be an array of the left column.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are getting an error when unpacking in this statement:

```
x,y = np.loadtxt(afile)
```

you should replace it for this:

```
x, y = zip(*np.loadtxt(afile))
```

the rest should work